# Running a function when another function is called

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

What I was planning to do is to run the function `fault()` when `getvoltage()` runs every 30 minutes.

`Fault()` is to print different warning messages depending on the voltage value retrieved by running `getvoltage()`.

I have inserting `fault()` at the end of `updatelabel()` however I get the folowing error: `NameError: name 'fault' is not defined`.

Sorry, this is my first time working on a project that requires Python coding so I'm rather new to how this works. I appreciate every help I can get.

Here's the snippet of my code:

```
def updatesetpoints():
    lowvolt = lowvoltentry.get()
    chargefail = chargerfailentry.get()
    failsafe = failsafeentry.get()
    failsafereset = failsaferesetentry.get()
    fault()

def fault():
    if (voltage < lowvolt and voltage > chargefail):
        print ("Battery Voltage Low")
    elif (voltage < chargefail and voltage > failsafe):
        print ("Battery Charger Fail")
    elif ( voltage < failsafe):
        print ("Fail Safe Vent Open")



def update_label(label):

    def getvoltage():

        f=open("VoltageReadings.txt", "a+")
        readings = [0]*100
        maxsample = 100
        counter = 0

        while (counter < maxsample):

            reading = adc.read_adc(0, gain=GAIN)
            readings.append(reading)
            counter += 1

        avg = sum(readings)/100
        global voltage
        volt= (avg * 0.1259)/100
        voltage = str(volt)       
        f.write("%.2f" % (volt) + "\r\n")
        readings.clear()

        label.config(text=str('Voltage: {0:.2f}'.format(volt)))
        label.after(1800000, getvoltage)
    getvoltage()
    fault()

class Batterysetpts(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.configure(bg="white")

        #Variables
        global lowvolt
        global chargefail
        global failsafe
        global failsafereset
        lowvolt = tk.DoubleVar()
        chargefail = tk.DoubleVar()
        failsafe = tk.DoubleVar()
        failsafereset = tk.DoubleVar()

        #Entry Label
        global lowvoltentry
        global chargerfailentry
        global failsafeentry
        global failsaferesetentry
        lowvoltentry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable = lowvolt)
        chargerfailentry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable = chargefail)
        failsafeentry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable = failsafe)
        failsaferesetentry = tk.Entry(self, textvariable = failsafereset)
        lowvoltentry.place(relx = 0.67, rely = 0.35, anchor = "center")
        chargerfailentry.place(relx = 0.67, rely = 0.5, anchor = "center")
        failsafeentry.place(relx = 0.67, rely = 0.65, anchor = "center")
        failsaferesetentry.place(relx = 0.67, rely = 0.8, anchor = "center")

        #Labels
        LV = tk.Label(self, text = "Low Voltage Set Point", font = LARGE_FONT, bg="white")
        CF = tk.Label(self, text = "Charger Fail Set Point", font = LARGE_FONT, bg="white")
        FS = tk.Label(self, text = "Fail Safe Open Set Point", font = LARGE_FONT, bg="white")
        FSR = tk.Label(self, text = "Fail Safe Reset Set Point", font = LARGE_FONT, bg="white") 
        LV.place(relx = 0.37, rely = 0.35, anchor = "center")
        CF.place(relx = 0.37, rely = 0.5, anchor = "center")
        FS.place(relx = 0.37, rely = 0.65, anchor = "center")
        FSR.place(relx = 0.37, rely = 0.8, anchor = "center")  


        #Confirm Button
        confirmupdatebutton = tk.Button(self, text = "Confirm Changes", command = updatesetpoints)
        confirmupdatebutton.place(relx= 0.5, rely= 0.9, anchor = "center")
```

Thank you in advance for giving a thought to this question and helping me out :)

Comment: How could this possibly work? ``fault()`` internally uses variables that are exclusive to ``updatesetpoints()``, what variables should ``fault()`` use when called from within ``update_label()``? Suggestion: promote ``fault()`` to a "top-level" function that accepts parameters.

Comment: Which of the two calls to `fault` produces the error?

Comment: @Aimery the call under update_label

Comment: @MikeScotty Oh, I see.. what if i were to global the variables? Do you reckon it'll work? I will also try to promote fault() as a top-level function thank you :)

Comment: @thediscreet global variables are usually not recommended. I'll second @MikeScotty: you should promote `fault()` to a "top-level" function with parameters.

Comment: @Aimery I have promoted `fault()` however now I have the error `NameError: name 'lowvolt' is not defined`

Comment: @Aimery sorry i think i left out a part of the code, i will update my post, please check the newly updated code thank you for your help!

Comment: @MikeScotty sorry i think i left out a part of the code, i will update my post, please check the newly updated code thank you for your help!

Comment: In your updated code, ``fault()`` is still a sub-function of ``updatesetpoints()``. I do not see, how adding the class ``Batterysetpts`` to the question makes any difference in regards to the issue.

Comment: @MikeScotty So sorry I was careless with the edit, I have just amended it

Answer (score 0):

My quick take at fixing your code (disclaimer, I haven't tested it):

```
def updatesetpoints():
lowvolt = lowvoltentry.get()
chargefail = chargerfailentry.get()
failsafe = failsafeentry.get()
failsafereset = failsaferesetentry.get()
fault()

def fault(voltage):
    # Here voltage is a parameter (and thus local to the function)
    if (voltage < lowvolt and voltage > chargefail):
        print ("Battery Voltage Low")
    elif (voltage < chargefail and voltage > failsafe):
        print ("Battery Charger Fail")
    elif ( voltage < failsafe):
        print ("Fail Safe Vent Open")

def update_label(label):
    def getvoltage():
        f=open("VoltageReadings.txt", "a+")
        readings = [0]*100
        maxsample = 100
        counter = 0
        while (counter < maxsample):
            reading = adc.read_adc(0, gain=GAIN)
            readings.append(reading)
            counter += 1
        avg = sum(readings)/100
        volt= (avg * 0.1259)/100
        # Global variable voltage should not be needed any more
        f.write("%.2f" % (volt) + "\r\n")
        readings.clear()
        label.config(text=str('Voltage: {0:.2f}'.format(volt)))
        label.after(1800000, getvoltage)
        # We return the voltage
        return volt

    value = getvoltage()
    fault(value)
```

Note: the global variable `voltage` seems to be a `string`. Is there any particular reason for this? Using a `float` would seem more logical to me.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help however I have tried another method and got it to work, still using global variables though.. haha thanks!